# ViewController not conforming to UITableViewDataSource?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am new to swift. I don't know why this error is coming though I have put the functions which conforms to the UITableViewDataSource.

This is the error!

http://imgur.com/LZtJaZS

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
{    
    @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!
    var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.myTable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.items.count;
    }
     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }
}
```

Comment: It's in the image. With error! Posted the code as well.

Comment: Posted the code as well.

Comment: CheckOut this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479381/viewcontroller-does-not-confirm-to-protocol-uitableviewdatasource/26479497#26479497