# Swift UITableView Controller error: Type "ViewController" does not conform to protocol "UITableViewDataSource"

Tags: uitableviewsectionheader

```
import UIKit
class ViewController:UIViewController {
    var tableView:UITableView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView = UITableView(frame:view.bounds,style: .Plain)

        if let theTableView = tableView {
            theTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(),forCellReuseIdentifier:"identifier")

            theTableView.dataSource = self
            theTableView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight

            view.addSubview(theTableView)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

"theTableView.dataSource = self"  error message *Type "ViewController" does not conform to protocol "UITableViewDataSource"*

Comment: Error message you get is self-explanatory, your `ViewController` indeed doesn't conform to protocol `UITableViewDataSource`. There are a tons of questions about that, for example look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581780/type-viewcontroller-does-not-confirm-to-protocol-uitableviewdatasource)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare at the top that you're implementing the data source and delegate protocol, and then you need to actually implement those methods (at least numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. The same warning appears on the line "class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate"

Comment: Did you implement the data source methods? Update your question with the code you have now.