# Table View Controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, tableview, viewcontroller

I am getting an error that says "Type 'View Controller' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'"

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "meunSegue", sender: self)
    }
    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


        let secondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        secondViewController.recievedData = "hello"
    }

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var recievedData = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(recievedData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581780/type-viewcontroller-does-not-conform-to-protocol-uitableviewdatasource)

Comment: I think it is saying you need to implement UITableViewDataSource delegate methods.

Comment: ... or, more accurately, implement the two required methods of this protocol, namely [`numberOfRowsInSection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614931-tableview) and [`cellForRowAt`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview).

Comment: «Table View Controller» is not a really meaningful title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this two `tableView` delegation methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numberOfRows
}
```

Make sure set `table` delegation to `ViewController`

```
table.delegate = self
table.dataSource = self
```

Comment: delegate != datasource

Comment: @vikingosegundo, yep datasource added too ;-)